# Two crossword clues

Tags: crossword-clues

I don’t know why I’m making this, but here are 2 crossword clues off the top of my head. (And no, no crosswords for you!)

1. To play rock, paper, scissors agressively? (5, 5)
2. Apolitical reactionist? (7)

Answer (score 3):

Here is my guess for the first one:

To play rock, paper, scissors aggressively-

> THROW HANDS- Throw hands is slang for getting into a fistfight. 'Throw' is also the action of displaying your sign in Rock, Paper, Scissors.

---

Edit: A guess for the second one:

Apolitical reactionist-

> Is it REAGENT?- A+Regent (Political) and reagents are the things that cause a chemical reaction. Not sure about this one.

Comment: This is correct! Good job! All that’s left is the second.

Comment: @parz I have made a guess for the second one. Please take a look.

Comment: The second one is incorrect. Remember, these are crossword clues, not cryptics - I have zero business writing cryptics.

Answer (score 1):

1. 

> I think this is **SHAKE HANDS**, a sort of play on words suggesting a particularly aggressive game of rock, paper, scissors.

2. 

> I think this is **NEUTRON** which sounds apolitical ("neutral") but also sustains the chain reaction in a nuclear reactor ("reactionist").

Comment: Oof. Both are wrong, but good go!